# Create a shared dictionary in python to store events

Tags: python, events, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a shared dictionary in python which should hold created events.

```
# prepare shared dictionary which will hold our events
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
event_storage = mgr.dict()

# start webserver
w = WebServer(server['host'], server['port'])
p = Process(target=w.start, args=(event_storage,))
p.start()

for i, param in enumerate(_DEFS):
    for tc in testcases():
        # create and store event for current testcase
        request_id = get_new_rid()
        event_storage[request_id] = Event()  # problematic line

        # other code...
```

After executing this code i get an exception: 
**RuntimeError: Condition objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance**

Can anyone help me please to solve this problem or give me a hint how to share multiple events between processes?

Edit: My question is especially about the combination shared dictionary and events. The "possible duplicate" doesn't handle the question about sharing `Events()`. Changing

```
event_storage[request_id] = Event()  # problematic line
```

to

```
 event_storage[request_id] = "test  # problematic line
```

works - but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AmiTavory This shouldn't be a duplicate of the question you linked. If I change the "problematic line" to store a simple string everything works.
My question is about a shared dictionary to store events.

Comment: Thanks, retracted & reversed. You might consider in the future to reference on your own duplicate-looking questions, and pinpoint the delta.